# Visual Studio Code - Extension problems "Open In Browser" by Techer Failed to use

Tags: visual-studio-code

Open browser failed!! Please check if you have installed the browser chrome correctly!
I have installed an extension called "Open in Browser" but when I try it `ctrl` + `b`, not working and failed
[This is what happens when I try "ctrl + b"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1OoT.png)

I searched on google and found a reference telling me **"Go to settings -> Extensions -> Open in Browser and set a default browser."** but it's not working then i go to *defaultsettings.json* and i see something [When i open *defaultsettings.json and look for "open-in-browser.default"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDQ4H.jpg) it there is no browser that I have

I am confused and do not know what to do and hopefully it can be answered because this extension really helps me

Answer (score 1):

If you go back to the extensions pane and click on the "open in browser" extension, it should say "This extension is enabled globally" underneath the *Uninstall* button.

Before I was able to see that message, it said something like "extension has been disabled/restricted because it isn't trusted". So I had to "trust the workspace" to get the extension to work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to version from 2.0 to 1.1 and it works as intended.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).